# USB internet key stopped working on Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, usb, windows-8.1, connection, usb-modem

I have an USB internet key (Alcatel X200) that suddenly doesn't let me connect to internet anymore.

The weird thing about it is that the key is detected by Windows, its interface connects successfully to internet *but* Windows doesn't seem to recognize it at all. Even though the key's software says that I'm connected, I can't load any page.

Even if I'm connected in such manner, it doesn't show up on the connections list, the WiFi icon looks like this:

[image]

Also, WiFi connection doesn't work if the key is connected.

A couple years ago I changed my laptop and I upgraded to Win8.1 and since this key doesn't support Win8, I had to use Win7 drivers. This little trick used to work, but I have to reinstall drivers every time I unplug the key.

Do you have any ideas?